# Salary selection with bonuses mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables
users, salary, bonus, penalty 
I want to select salary including all bonuses and penalties for some user
I have user_id in each table(salary, bonus, penalty)
how can I do that
there can be two or more bonuses and penalties
I tried to do

```
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(salary.salary) + SUM(bonus.bonus) - SUM(penalty.penalty) FROM users
   INNER JOIN salary on salary.user_id = users.id 
   INNER JOIN bonus on bonus.user_id = users.id
   INNER JOIN penalty on penalty.user_id = users.id;
   END
```

but I had multiple results for each bonus and penalty
I wanted to have only one number
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a given user could have multiple records in each of the `salary`, `bonus`, and `penalty` tables, one safe approach here would be to just aggregate the amounts in separate subqueries, and then join together the results:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    COALESCE(s.salary, 0) + COALESCE(b.bonus, 0) - COALESCE(p.penalty, 0) AS amount
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(salary) AS salary
    FROM salary
    GROUP BY user_id
) s
    ON u.id = s.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(bonus) AS bonus
    FROM bonus
    GROUP BY user_id
) b
    ON u.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(penalty) AS penalty
    FROM penalty
    GROUP BY user_id
) p
    ON u.id = p.user_id
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to above to restrict to one or more users, e.g.

```
WHERE u.id = some_value
```

Comment: what is u.id )) i can't get it, sorry

Comment: Do you know what an _alias_ is?  `u.id` means the same thing as `users.id` more or less.

Comment: ty, i will try it and mark as solved if it goes right